# Get latitude and longitude based on zip using Geocoder class in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, geocoding

I got the current location based on Longitude and latitude values 
and then I also got Multiple places on google map using Annotation 
now I want get longitude and latitude values based on Zip code 
I don't know how to get Longitude and latitude values base on Zip code

Comment: try google map api for geocoding

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this  is the method for call  google map api for geocoding, if u pass the Zipcode/Postal code, you get the result

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{ 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@",yourzipcodetext/PostalcodeText.text]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSString *lataddr=[[[[[dict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lat"];

NSString *longaddr=[[[[[dict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lng"];


NSLog(@"The resof latitude=%@", lataddr);

NSLog(@"The resof longitude=%@", longaddr);


}
```

**Chioce-2**

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"ZIP CODE HERE" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Latitude %f", coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"Longitude %f", coordinate.longitude);
    }];
```

Comment: it is your zip code /Postal code text or string, you pass the value and then u get the response, are you understand

Comment: thk for replay i will try

Comment: NSString *Zipcodetext; and then set Zipcodetext.text but it's error(property text not found on object NSString ) and then How to pass the my zip code number like 534401

Comment: gt create the NSString *zipcode=534401; k and replace the Zipcode to the Zipcodetext.text on the URL, k

Comment: Thank bro i got output thk bro

Comment: is this free API from google or there is any limit of usage or any kinda charges...??

Comment: @MPG it is the open source /free api

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I want to fetch location/region based on Lat-Long value. How is it possible?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - can u give a example which type u need i give the answer to u

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Instead on appending postal code in request I want to append Lat-Long (say 19.23424, 34.12123) value and response should return particular region in city (say Andheri in Mumbai). Is this possible?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - it is possible if u pass directly http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Andheri,Mumbai         u get the answer ,

Comment: @Raja - it is based on response

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik. Okay. but i'm hitting same address. some time getting lat,lng. Some time getting NULL responce and some time getting HTML responce. how will i handle it. Please help me if you had faced this already

HTML response:

<content_url><![CDATA[http://203.122.12.242:2002/userportal/NSCCONTENT.do?requesturi=http%3a%2f%2fmaps%2egoogle%2ecom%2fmaps%2fapi%2fgeocode%2fjson%3fsensor%3dfalse%26address%3d610104&ip=10%2e0%2e1%2e134&mac=74%3a1b%3ab2%3a29%3a20%3a69&nas=aerovoyce&requestip=maps%2egoogle%2ecom&sc=9f491d49d008fc568408c965a3d3bcf0]]></content_url>
</msc>

Comment: Currently it doesn't work. Google API now requires an api key.

Comment: @dpart - thank you verymuch, I will update the answer based on the new one

Answer (score 12):

It will be as simple as something like this:

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"ZIP CODE HERE" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Latitude %f", coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"Longitude %f", coordinate.longitude);
    }];
```

Comment: thk for replay  i got Latitude and longitude but it's showing different location plz help me thk in advanced

Answer (score 2):

Apple released good documentation on [forward geocoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html) that should help you.