# How to get distance and location using zipcode in iOS?

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, distance, zipcode

I am developing an instant messaging chat app.In which the user have to enter it's zipcode and when he will go for the search option there is a particular radius in miles given by him through which the search operation will perform.So now I have two zipcode one is user's and another is my friend's zipcode from that how can I get the users within that radius  between them and their location.Can you please help me how to proceed and which frameworks i should use to get these.Please help me as I am a newbe in iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the zip code / address into a lat/long position using `CLGeocoder`. Once you have those positions you can:

If you want the actual distance use `CLLocation` and `distanceFromLocation:`.

If you want the driving distance you need to use a navigation framework to get directions, like `MKDirections`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to or where to get navigation framework?

Comment: `MKDirections`? Its part of MapKit

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354490/latitude-and-longitude-based-on-zip-code) to get Latitude and Longitude from zipcode. Once you get the zipcodes of your source and destination, you can get the distance using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077425/finding-distance-between-cllocationcoordinate2d-points/11077442#11077442).

Please note that it will be air distance and not the actual distance. You can evaluate Google Map or direction API to find actual distance.

Comment: can you please suggest me which framework should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for getting the distance between 2 zipcode but you can use [google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595538/get-latitude-and-longitude-based-on-zip-using-geocoder-class-in-ios)  for getting the lat long of your zip code and then using those lat long you can find the distance between the zipcodes.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```